# Send mail perl if the file extension not match

Tags: perl, email

I want to send an email when there is file with an extension other than `.xlsx` in the directory.

The script below sends an email when there is no file in the directory. I need to change it so it finds files with an unrecognized file extension (one that's not `.xlsx`).

```
my @files = sort( grep { -f "$cur_wrk_dir/$_" && /\.xlsx$/ }  readdir D); #read files    
my $filecount = scalar(@files);
if ($filecount < 1);
{  
    print ("No  xlsx file found  $hvr_agent_arg.\n");
    mailfunctional  ("Geen $program_agent_arg no xlsx file found in $source_dir"  ,"$env2 no file for $program_channelname", $email_to2  , $email_from);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my @files = readdir $dh;

my @bad = grep { !/\.xlsx\z/ } @files;
if ( @bad ) {
   ...
}
```

If you don't need the list of bad files,

```perl
my @files = readdir $dh;

if ( grep { !/\.xlsx\z/ } @files ) {
   ...
}
```